# Sign in and update user doc collide with onAuthStateChange

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function to sign in to Firebase and also update the user doc with new stuff, by using `merge: true`. The issue however is that simoltanously I have the `onAuthStateChanged` listener that listens to new login and then reads the user doc.

What happens is that updating the user doc, and reading the user doc will happen somewhat simoltenously. Here are the functions:

```
export const signInAndUpdateUserObject =
  (provider: AuthProvider) => async (): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const { user } = (await signInWithPopup(provider)()) ?? {};
      if (!user) {
        return;
      }

      await setDoc(doc(getFirestore(), 'users', user.uid), {}, { merge: true }); // Merging an empty object
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

export const initAuth = (): void => {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      const docRef = doc(getFirestore(), 'users', user.uid);
      const exists = await getDoc(docRef);
      console.log(exists); // THIS WILL SHOW AN EMPTY OBJECT
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
};
```

(The initAuth function executes when the app starts).
Please note that for this example I'm updating the user doc with an empty object, just to make the example simple. Since `merge` is set to true, the firestore doc won't be affected at all. However when reading the user doc in the `onAuthStateChanged`, it will for a strange reason read just the merged object, not the actual user doc, so if I update the user doc with merging an empty object, then in onAuthStateChanged, it will read an empty object. If I would update the user doc with `merge: false`, technically there would be no problem, and the whole user doc would be read correctly, but I wouldn't like to do that.

How can I overcome this problem?

Just to prove the collision, I introduced setTimeOut into the onAuthStateChanged, and then it works fine:

```
export const initAuth = (): void => {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        const docRef = doc(getFirestore(), 'users', user.uid);
        const exists = await getDoc(docRef);
        console.log(exists); // Will show the complete user doc object
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: "it will for a strange reason read just the merged object, not the actual user doc" Can you show the data that you get back from the call, and the data that you expect to get back?

Comment: The data that I get back is an empty object, because that's what I pass when setting the doc (with merge), and what I expect is the actual object on firestore which is {a:2} and whatever props that are there. When I set the doc with merge and pas an empty object, the remote object on firestore isn't affected of course

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're getting a result from the local cache with partial data. If that's the case, the `metadata.fromCache` property if the snapshot should be `true`, and probably its `metadata.hasPendingWrites` too. See the [reference docs for `metadata`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.snapshotmetadata.md#snapshotmetadata_class) for more on these.

The options I can think of:

- Specify that you want to get the value from the server with [source options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options)
- Attach a [realtime listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) and wait until you get an update with `fromCache` and `hasPendingWrites` being false.